# how to use StreamController to broadcast in AngularDart

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, angular-controller

I am learning [StreamController](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.68.0/dart-async/StreamController-class.html). There are three components: ComponentA, ComponentB, ComponentC. What I would like to implement is: if user click any one component, `funcA()`, `funcB()`, `funcC()` are called exactly one.
Any problem in my following design? Thanks

```
ComponentA {
  ClickService _service;
  ComponentA(this._service) {
    _service.clickStream.stream.listen(funcA);
  }

  void funcA {
    // do something
  }

  // click event handler
  void onClick(Event data) {
    _service.fireEvent(data);
  }
}

ComponentB {
  ClickService _service;
  ComponentB(this._service) {
    _service.clickStream.stream.listen(funcB);
  }

  void funcB {
    // do something
  }

  // click event handler
  void onClick(Event data) {
    _service.fireEvent(data);
  }
}

ComponentC {
  ClickService _service;
  ComponentC(this._service) {
    _service.clickStream.stream.listen(funcC);
  }

  void funcC {
    // do something
  }

  // click event handler
  void onClick(Event data) {
    _service.fireEvent(data);
  }
}

@Injectable()
class ClickService {
  final clickStream = new StreamController<Event>.broadcast();
  void fireEvent(Event data) {
    clickStream.add(data);
  }
}
```

template of ComponentA

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)">Click A!</button>
```

template of ComponentB

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)">Click B!</button>
```

template of ComponentC

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)">Click C!</button>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: What does not look good is `onClick()` vs `onClick(Data data)`, `Data data` won't be passed automagically. `(click)="onClick($event)"` would work with `onClick(Event event)` though.

Comment: Also ensure the service is only provided once, for example at the root level. If you provide it at a component, you'll get as many service instances as you get instances of that component.

Comment: You still have the invalid `Data` in `void onClick(Data data) {`

Comment: That was the wrong change :D `(click)="onClick(Data data)"` should be `(click)="onClick($event)"`, but the handler needs to accept an `Event` object `void onClick(Event data) {`